# How can you move margins to a single word page with Visual basic application 7.1?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a `word document` with a `bookmark` where I have to load a table of contents.
When running a `VBA macro(Microsoft visual basic for aplications 7.1)` and trying to load the table in the `bookmark` he stretches on a second page being too large. 
I need to change the margins of the page with the `bookmark`, not to the entire document, so the table fits in only one page.
I've tried to select the `bookmark` text and then apply the changes to the selection, but it applies to the whole document.

Here is the code I tried:

```
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("bmTable").Select
        With Selection.PageSetup
            .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(-1)
            .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
            .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
        End With
    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would decreasing the font size help

Comment: Margins cannot be set for a particular selection. Instead, you can add a section break before and after the page in question, and change the page setup for the particular section. This way, the rest of the document would not be affected.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to move cursor to the specific section? Would work if I look for the specific bookmark in that section using this Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToField, Name:="bmTable" @Arul

Comment: won't help @ApurvPawar

Comment: Have you tried setting the table indent to a negative value? `.Tables(1).Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-50, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone`

Comment: @BogdanSorin, you can use `Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="YourBookmark"` to go to the specific bookmark.

Comment: Tried what you said with sections, added new section and applied settings for that section. Now I encounter another problem. When I execute the macro I'm getting this error 4198-Command failed. First a save file dialog pops than I'm getting a message box with that error. @Arul

Comment: @BogdanSorin, at which line are you getting the error. Also, can you post the relevant code.

Comment: `Doc.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = wdSeekFirstPageHeader`. this is the line where I'm getting the error. @Arul

Comment: I'm sorry @Bogdan. I don't think I can try without seeing your full code.